# NPM: Sharp, Canvas and Windows - The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: npm

Sharp cannot run with Canvas on windows:

Error: The specified procedure could not be found.

This is a documented issue, but no solution

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#prerequisites

## [image]

Any idea how to overcome this?